# Spring Integration SFTP fileExistsMode for mv operation

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp, spring-integration-file

Why is not possible use FileExistsMode in case of mv operation? Is FAIL default value for mv operation?

```kotlin
AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.MV
```

```kotlin
.fileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.REPLACE)
```

[image]

Why not in MV case? Maybe pull request in next ver?

Answer (score 0):

The logic there in the `SftpSession` is like this:

```
public void rename(String pathFrom, String pathTo) throws IOException {
    if (this.sftpClient.getVersion() >= SftpConstants.SFTP_V5) {
        this.sftpClient.rename(pathFrom, pathTo, SftpClient.CopyMode.Overwrite);
    }
    else {
        remove(pathTo);
        this.sftpClient.rename(pathFrom, pathTo);
    }
}
```

So, it is always override existing file.

You may consider to use `SftpFileTemplate.exists()` before sending an MV command.

We indeed may consider to improve `AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.mv()` logic to use provided `FileExistsMode`. Feel free to raise a GH issue and contribute such a feature.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Good to know, it depends on version.
On screenshot:
spring-integration-sftp:6.1.3 sshd-sftp:2.9.2

I updated app to uses spring-integration-sftp:6.2.0 sshd-sftp:2.11.0 and works well.

rename method implementation in 6.2.0
[image]